# .htaccess 3 different domains , 3 different 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

currently I am running Magento with 3 different Domains. I want to have a 301 rewrite rule for each of those 3, so "www." gets added to them when the user types in "domain.de"

For example: domain.de gets rewritten as www.domain.de

Currently my code is the following:

```
Rewriteengine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.de$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.de$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem is the code is causing a redirect loop and I have no idea what the problem could be.
I would be very glad if someone could tell me what's wrong with the code...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.de$` is a negative condition and that matches for other 2 domains as well.

Replace your 3 rules with this single rule:

```
Rewriteengine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.